# update version number in README.md during gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, markdown

I am working on an Android library (aar) project. The project contains a README.md file which in turn contains these lines:

```
   ... declare library dependency:

   Gradle: `compile 'com.acme:mylibrary:1.0.0@aar'`
```

My `gradle.properties` file contains:

`VERSION_NAME=1.0.0`

The problem is that currently I have to keep two files manually in sync. What I would like to do is keep the `VERSION_NAME` property and substitute it's value into `README.md`

Comment: What you need to do is to filter the md file during build using copy task and  filter with `ReplaceTokens`. Is this project hosted online? I will have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but the project is in a private repo, at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some pattern to find out where you used the version number it could be as easy as creating a tasks and replacing text based on a regex.

Something like:

```
task replaceVersionInREADME << {
    // Maven
    ant.replaceregexp(match:'<version>([0-9\\.]+)</version>', replace:"<version>${version}</version>", flags:'g', byline:true) {
        fileset(dir: '.', includes: 'README.md')
    }
    // Gradle
    ant.replaceregexp(match:'com\\.acme\\:mylibrary\\:([0-9\\.]+)', replace:"com.acme:mylibrary:${version}", flags:'g', byline:true) {
        fileset(dir: '.', includes: 'README.md')
    }
}
```

Change the regex as you need.

Comment: For android/gradle, one could also do rootProject.afterEvaluate { .. pack ant.replace in here }